# EF Repository not inserting data in DB when upper method catches exception

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, async-await, repository, aspnetboilerplate

I'm working on a ASP.NET Core application.

I got an AppService async task that calls a different AppService method that gets a list of data needed for Registration,

```
public async Task<RegisterOutput> Register(RegisterInput input)
{
    var testTask =  profileAppService.GetTestData();
    await testTask;
    UnitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChanges();
    ...
}
```

profileAppService class has the method

```
public async Task<TestDto> GetTestData()
{
    ...

    long entityId = _entityRepository.InsertAndGetId(entity);
    entityDependency.EntityId = entity;
    _entityDependencyRepository.Insert(entityDependency);
    UnitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now if Register() works fine, it does store data in the database. 
If Register() catches an exception, the data is not saved, even though

```
_entityRepository.InsertAndGetId(entity)
```

does return a proper id in the database. (f.e. id is 100, this entity is skipped, and in the current table I got ... 99, 101, ...)

So my problem is - Why doesn't it store the data if Register() method catches an exception? How do I store the data in this case?

The UnitWorkManager saving changes are for research purposes to see if they solve my problem, but apparently they didn't. I am open for any good practice advices aswell

Comment: If exception occurred, execution stops at that line. If you need to complete your execution you should handle exception and continue another scenario that you can place to another method. if you need to execute some code when it doesn't matter exception occurred or not you can use `try{}catch(Exception ex){}finally{}` blocks and place your code into finally block, this block always executes.

Comment: In this particular case I don't mind an exception occuring. What I don't get is, why didn't it save it, even though it claims it did

Comment: If I understood correctly, you mentioned that `Register()` method catch an exception, so maybe your `UnitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChanges();` didn't called? In this case you can wrap your logic into try/catch and move `UnitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChanges();` to `finally{ UnitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChanges(); }` block

Comment: What I don't get is, why didn't you catch the exception, even though you claim you did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a separate unit of work to handle your case;

```cs
public class MySampleClass
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWorkManager _unitOfWorkManager;

    public MySampleClass(IUnitOfWorkManager unitOfWorkManager)
    {
        _unitOfWorkManager = unitOfWorkManager;
    }

    private void MyDbMethod()
    {
        using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
        {
            //Do your db operations...
            await _unitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChangesAsync();
            await uow.CompleteAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

See https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work#unit-of-work-scope